# how to skip all backslash-newline but retain newline in antlr4?

Tags: java, antlr4

Statements in my language are terminated by newline but I want the statements to be formatted over multiple lines by inserting backslash-newlines.

```
"This is a statement."
"This is also \
a statement."
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to skip backslash-newline. Clearly ESC_NEWLINE is not being recognized but I don't know how to fix it. Help is appreciated.

The lexer has

```
SKIP_TOKENS :  (WS | ESC_NEWLINE) -> skip;
ESC_NEWLINE : '\\'NEW_LINE;
NEWLINE : NEW_LINE;

COMMENT :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* ;

ID     :  (LETTER|'_') (LETTER|DIGIT|'_')* ;
STRING :  '"' ( ~('\\'|'"') )* '"' ;

fragment LETTER          : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT           : ('0' | NON_ZERO_DIGIT);
fragment NON_ZERO_DIGIT  : [1-9] ;
fragment NEW_LINE        : \r?\n ;
fragment WS              : [ \t]+;
```

Parser is

```
script: line* EOF;

line: COMMENT NEWLINE
    | statement COMMENT? NEWLINE;


statement: STRING | ID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer tries to match as many characters for a lexer rule. Because of that, the `\\n` (backslash + line break) inside the input:

```
"This is also \
a statement."
```

will never become a token that can be skipped and then let the `" ... "` become a `STRING` token. You will need to let that backslash + line break be a part of the `STRING` token:

```
STRING : '"' ( ~[\\"] | '\\' NEW_LINE )* '"';

fragment NEW_LINE : '\r'? '\n';
```

If you do not want to let the backslash + line break be a part of the `STRING` token, you will need to preprocess the input and strip it beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. Stripping in preprocessing is the way to go. My actual use case is more complicated than this and would require adding \\n in a bazillion places.  Good to know I'm not missing anything in antlr.